# Are there any tools that helps to plan schedules and costs of a travel?

Tags: planning, travel-tools

I already planned some travels before using Microsoft Excel to plan paths, schedule, costs, transports, hotels and all things related to a long travel... Now, I'm intending to plan another one to 2013 that would be very complex to plan(a lot of points to see, airplanes, cabs, etc... and a lot of possibilities to decide)...

Does someone know a good tool(software or website) that could help me to plan everything that could affect my travel???

I was thinking on using [Microsoft Project](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_project) or even [Primavera Project Planner](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Primavera_%28software%29) (after all, all travels could be seen as projects with activities, "tasks", schedule, etc...) It is feasible?? Does someone already experienced such thing??

Comment: I hope this is not a holiday. ;) It sounds like you want to pack a lot of action in little time. And, to paraphrase a well known saying, "your best travel experiences happen in between your planned moments".

Comment: Or you could just go with it :) Have a start and a finish, and the surprise will be what happens in between!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is [duffelup.com](http://duffelup.com). I used it to plan a trip some time ago, but it is very shiny and therefor quite limited.

But maybe you can use it for your needs...